# How to add fallback or avoid geting error when api returns NULL for image src in REACT JS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, image, src

```js
<img className="cast-card__avatar" style={{backgroundImage: `url(${person.image.medium})`}}/>
```

1. `person.image.medium` is returning null value getting error due to this how to provide a fallback
2. person is object returned from api call person.image.medium has images but some of them contain null  values getting error due to this

   ```
    <img className="cast-card__avatar"
       src={person.image.medium}
       onError={addDefaultSrc}/>

   const addDefaultSrc = (ev) => {
    ev.target.src =
      "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1555952517-2e8e729e0b44?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=400&q=80";
   };
   ```

3 i tried out this also but this too doesnt work

Comment: We need to see more of your code in order to help.

Comment: i think it  is `src` not `style={{backgroundImage: .....`

Answer (score 1):

You have two options.

**Option 1**

Only render the image if `person.image.medium` exists:

```js
{person.image.medium && <img className="cast-card__avatar" src={person.image.medium} />}
```

**Option 2**

Render a default image if `person.image.medium` does not exist:

```js
<img className="cast-card__avatar" src={person.image.medium || "default.jpg"} />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple backgrounds, if first one is not available it will go for the second one and so on.

Try this:

```
<div 
    className="cast-card__avatar" 
    style={{backgroundImage: `url(${person.image.medium}), url(${fallback_image_1}), url(${fallback_image_2})`}}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to handle this, see below.

```
{person && person.image && person.image.medium && <img className="cast-card__avatar" style={{backgroundImage: `url(${person.image.medium}}}/>}
```

Image tag should have a src, so chnage `img` to `div`

```
<div className="cast-card__avatar" style={{backgroundImage: `url(${person.image.medium || 'falback-image.jpg'}}}/>
```

You can also try like this

```
<img className="cast-card__avatar"
    src={person.image.medium || 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1555952517-2e8e729e0b44?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=400&q=80'}/>
```